# How do I reduce the size of the JCheckBox icon?

Tags: java, swing, jcheckbox

I need to reduce the size of a JCheckBox item, which has no text. So far I tried to override the methods `getPreferredSize()` and `getMaximumSize()`. Also setting the Font size or the size of the JCheckBox itself doesn't evoke any changes. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about an Icon that is added to the JCheckBox, then best would be to create a new Icon from a new Image that is a resize of the original image. You can do this with a Image by calling the `yourImage.getScaledInstance(...);` method.  Once you get the new image, create a `new ImageIcon(newImage)` and use it with your JCheckBox.

e.g.

```
Image oldImage = oldIcon.getImage();
Image newImage = oldImage.getScaledInstance(newWidth, newHeight, 
      Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);
Icon newIcon = new ImageIcon(newImage);
checkBox.setIcon(newIcon);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the paint function like this:

```
final JCheckBox cb = new JCheckBox("",autoChangeTab) {
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.scale(.9, .9);
        super.paint(g);
    }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

`getPreferredSize` and `getMaximumSize` only return the values assigned to `preferredSize` and `maximumSize`, respectively, for the `JCheckBox` object. If you want to change these values, use `setPreferredSize` and `setMaximumSize` instead:

```
jCheckBox.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 300));
```

and/or:

```
jCheckBox.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(200, 600));
```

Comment: You didn't test this, did you?